# contact us page link removed

Tags: usability, content

Client asked me to remove the "contact us" page   and place the contact information in the footer , i believe this is very awkward. do you agree
Note : 
the website is for architect design studio

[image]

Comment: Is this a question about implementation?

Comment: given this is a UX site I'm prepared to interpret 'believe this is very awkward' as the OP feeling the design is awkward to use as oppose to awkward to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the footer does not need a long scroll to show up, I think this design is good.

If all you had in that 'contact us' page was just this small to fit in a footer, this new design would also be getting rid of unnecessary white space and an additional click.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to this problem is to have both.

Create a contact us page. This page will be rich in detail and can include things such as:

- a list of relevant contacts at the company, including names, emails, phone numbers etc.
- location map(s)
- a contact form
- company social media
- a set of FAQs for common contact us issues
- links to other relevant pages like terms, delivery, privacy policy etc.

generally far too much for a footer.

Then in the footer provide condensed information such as a primary customer service contact, head office address and a link to the richer contact page.

You could also provide page relevant contact info in the footer (or possibly in a separate panel on the page) pointing the user in the direction of a business representative who can deal specifically with enquiries about the content on the page. Incidentally, this could work very nicely in the site you show as I assume projects like large architectural works have a main contact for the team.

This way you get the benefit of contact information being on all pages but also the benefit of having rich contact data and also a shareable URL to your contact data for social media and SEO

Answer (score 0):

Having too many pages can be a bad experience for the user too.

Typically the "Contact Us" page link would be located in the footer anyway, so if anything you are cutting out an unnecessary stage.